# Flask Logging - Debug setting

Tags: python, logging, flask

I am using the following config for my Flask app:

```
class StagingConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    MONGO_DB_NAME = "res_stage_database"

    @classmethod
    def init_app(cls, app):
        import logging
        from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
        rotating_handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename='gunicorn.out', maxBytes=10000000, backupCount=5)
        rotating_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
        rotating_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        app.logger.addHandler(rotating_handler)
        app.logger.info("Using StagingConfig")
        app.logger.error("Using StagingConfig")
```

(Above, appends only the error message to `gunicorn.out`-
2015-04-26 18:03:38,182 - ERROR - Using StagingConfig )

Since this config is used in a staged app, I want DEBUG to be False, so that I dont get Flask debug screens in case of errors, and instead the standard error 500 screen. Although for some reason, when DEBUG is set to False, logging of error messages except error stops.

As soon as `DEBUG` is set to True, logging occurs correctly. Shouldn't these values be independent, since I set my log level on the logging handler?

Answer (score 6):

Turns out I had to use         `app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`, instead of setting the level on the handler.

Comment: Thanks - this just ended a very frustrating time trying to get logging working in a flask app while following the official instructions.

Comment: On Heroku, unfortunately, that did not re-enable logging (using Flask and gunicorn). What ended up working was the code snippet posted [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/379#issuecomment-7904270). Cheers